# Angular 2 Declaration expected & Unterminated regular expression error

Tags: angular

I am using Angular 2. and this error comes when I run the code:

```
ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(3,31): error TS1109: Expression expected.
src/app/app.component.ts(3,39): error TS1146: Declaration expected.
src/app/app.component.ts(3,40): error TS1161: Unterminated regular expression li
```

app.component.ts

```
34.    onSubmit({value,valid}: {value:Roomsearch, valid:boolean}){
35.    this.getAll()
36.        .subscribe(
37.            rooms => this.rooms = rooms,
38.            err => {
39.           console.log(err);    
40.            }
41.         );  
42.    }
```

[part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vD1YS.png)

[part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wub8.png)

Comment: Share full code of component in which error generated

Comment: @HiteshKansagara. done . please check

Comment: line 3 should be "@angular/http" in quotes

Comment: corrected line number 3 issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In line 3

`import { Http, Response } from "@angular/http"`;

BTW, When you're watching `ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(3,39)`, it means error in line no `3`, not line number `31`.